# Как сгенерировать значение от 1 до p - 1 и с этим значением проверить условие на деление от остатка. Затем это значение присваивается в textBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста с моей проблемой, надеюсь я все  верно изъяснил.
вот мой код:

```
public static void Generation()
    {
        User u = new User();
        try
        {
            int p = Int32.Parse(u.number_p.Text);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int g = rand.Next(1, p - 1);
            if (p % g == 1)
            {
                u.number_g.Text = g.ToString();
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(u, $"Число сгенерировано = {g}", "Уведомление");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(u, $"Возникла ошибка {ex}", "Уведомление");
        }
    }
```

здесь как видно я от числа в другой форме генерирую значение, затем я делаю проверку, что при делении числа p на число g должен выйти остаток 1, и если все верно, то он присваивается в textbox.
Но вместо этого получаю ошибку что в этой строке "int p = Int32.Parse(u.number_p.Text);" - введено неверное значение. Или неверный формат данных.
Заранее спасибо!!!
вот текст исключения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и сама форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Точный текст исключения надо приаодить. Если исключение, значит там не число. Или не целое число.

Comment: я внес изменения в свой вопрос по сути я здесь конвертирую в число поле текстовое и все а при вводе целого числа выкинул исключение. Вот тут и вопрос что не так

Comment: Отлаживайте, выведите значение в `MessageBox` или консоль студии `Debug.WriteLine`. Я без понятия, что такое `number_p` и как туда попадает значение. Если вы сделаете `Int32.Parse("13")`, то исключения не будет.

Comment: число p это число, которое делит по остатку на число g, п коду и форме вроде все понятно должно быть, не знаю как еще более детально изъяснить свою проблему. Получается в число g может войти такие числа, как: 2,3,4,6.

Comment: Отладкой научитесь пользоваться, это самой базовый и нужный инструмент любого разработчика. Вот слева от строки, которая дает вам ошибку, поставьте точку остановки, или до нее напишите `Debugger.Break();`, запустите проект, введите все данные, нажмите кнопку, и у вас студия остановится там, где стоит точка, двигаясь шаг за шагом через F10, смотрите какие значения у вас лежать в переменных. Если вам говорит "входная строка фиговая", значит вы даете не число, другого просто быть не может. Отладить свой проект займет у вас пару сек, но уже 3 часа ждете ответа от тех, кто не видят ваш код...

Comment: Вот остановка в 16 строке там же где и была. Скрин выше

Comment: и...? На `.Text` наведите, и посмотрите значение внутри этого свойства, которое вы пытаетесь перевести в `int`. Вам ведь выше верно сказали, если написать `Convert.ToInt32("13");`, то вы не получите ошибку, а значит у вас в `.Text` не `"13"`, как вы ожидаете, там может быть запятая, точка, проблем, да все что угодно, вот это и отслеживайте через отладку.

Comment: в общем я не правильно вывожу формат данных я вывожу int а по требует string. Буду тут думать как решать

Comment: в общем он получал 0 почему то я решил сделать метод в корневом классе формы и все вышло. Код тот же не могу понять почему он значения не получал